# Integral 0 to pi/2 using montecarlo in R

Tags: r, montecarlo, integral, calculus

Trying to  find integral (o to pi/2) of    x^2 cosx using montecarlo method. This is  my first time so need some direction. To generate random number should I transform the limit of the integral to (0,1) or can I generate random numbers with the given limit (0 to pi/2) ?

something like this ?

transform the integral from (o to pi/2) to (0to 1) which tranforms the function to 1/x^2 sinx generate random number rnorm(10000,0,1)

or Is there a way to generate random number like this rnorm(10000,0,1)*pi/2 with out having to transform the limit of the integral

Comment: People love to downvote here (i upvote)...but show some code first.

Comment: Can the down voters please comment why so I can use the feed back in future ?

Comment: @greenH0rn About downvotes. Your question is basically asking: can I generate uniformly distributed random numbers in given interval in R? The answer is - yes you can and it is easily findable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate random numbers uniformly in any interval you want, for example, `runif(1000,0,pi/2)` will generate a sample of size 1000 uniformly distributed on [0,π/2].  You definitely don't want to use `rnorm` here -- `rnorm` generates normally distributed data, not uniformly distributed data.

You could do your monte carlo simulation like this:

```
> f<-function(x) x^2 * cos(x)
> mean(f(runif(100000,0,pi/2)))*(pi/2)
[1] 0.4672985
```

Or, you can let R do the integration using `integrate`:

```
> integrate(f,0,pi/2)
0.4674011 with absolute error < 5.2e-15
```

Comment: Because you need to sample the entire space uniformly, there's no point in calculating the same point twice in this case (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: Normally distributed data will give some parts of the interval more weight than others.  Uniformly distributed data will give equal weight, which is what you want when computing an integral.

Comment: maybe a dumb question but why is not advisable to use normally distributed data ? Why is uniform distribution preferred ? also why do we need to multiply mean with pi/2 again ?

Comment: When you do an ordinary integral, by definition that assumes equal weighting (i.e. uniform distribution).  The normal distribution will give you a different weighting, and therefore a different (wrong) answer.  You multiply the mean by pi/2 because that is the length of the interval you are integrating over.  Also, these kinds of questions about integration are more appropriate for a math forum.  This board is about programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

My first shoot:

```
mc.integral = function(FUN, n.iter = 1000, interval){

  # take a sample using 'runif'
  x = runif(n.iter, interval[1], interval[2])

  # apply the user-defined function
  y = FUN(x)

  # calculate
  mean(y)*(interval[2] - interval[1])
}
```

#### example

```
FUN = function(x){x^2 * cos(x)}
integ = mc.integral(FUN, interval = c(0, pi/2))
print(integ)

[1] 0.4693398
```

Comment: very cool Fernando , I will check this out